# ItemsControl does not update the ItemsSource binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an `ObservableCollection<string>` bound to a `ItemsControl` as the `ItemsSource`, the binding works fine from the VM to the View but if I change the content of the binding in the `TextBox` it will not update the `ObservableCollection` that it is bound to.

I can't seem to work out why, does anyone know why this is?

Here is my code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Metrics, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Name="CalibrationNameTB"  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource baseStyle}" Margin="0, 1" Padding="5, 1" Width="270" FontSize="12"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: `Text="{Binding .}"` will not replace a string in the ItemsSource collection. You'll have to use a wrapper class with a string property.

Comment: @Clemens would you be able to point me in the right direction of how this would be implemented?

Comment: Instead of `ObservableCollection<string>` use `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` with a MyItem class that has a string property to which you bind in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: Post the ViewModel code also please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update a `string` because it's immutable.

What you should do is to replace the `ObservableCollection<string>` with an `ObservableCollection<YourType>` where `YourType` is a class with a public `string` property that you can get or set:

```
class YourType : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _theString;
    public string TheString
    {
        get { return _theString; }
        set { _theString = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then you bind to this property in your XAML markup:

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox Name="CalibrationNameTB"  Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TheString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource baseStyle}" Margin="0, 1" Padding="5, 1" Width="270" FontSize="12"/>
</WrapPanel>
```